# Are possible wrap in repeat list 2-column group to other column in container in CSS Grid layout?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a fixed height of my container with a list group in 2 column - sortable1 and sortable2 with `grid-auto-rows: 1fr`. List items in the 2-columns group are always the same.
Are possible list elements which overflow container height wrap to the next column?

What I have:
[image: What I have]

What I need(want):
[image: What I need(want)]

List may be different.

Document structure:
[image: Document structure]

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  height: 400px;
  background: red;
}
.columnlist {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.5fr 1.5fr;
  grid-template-areas: "sortable1 sortable2";
  padding: 20px;
}
#sortable1 {
  grid-area: sortable1;
  display: grid;
}

#sortable1 li {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

#sortable2 {
  grid-area: sortable2;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
}

#sortable2 li {
  background: rgb(255, 250, 205);
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ol,
ul {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="columnlist">
    <ul id="sortable1">
      <li>title 1</li>
      <li>title 2</li>
      <li>title 3</li>
      <li>title 4</li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="sortable2">
      <li>1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.  </li>
      <li>2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus sit amet vestibulum risus, vitae condimentum mi. Vivamus eu finibus dui. Fusce mollis lorem vel dui imperdiet, nec viverra lectus tempus. </li>
      <li>3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </li>
      <li>4 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus sit amet vestibulum risus. </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Maybe you can post an illustration of your desired outcome.

Comment: Hello, I'll add screenshots that I have and what I need. And try to draw the structure of my Grid. When my rows limit on my container height they are wrapping to the second column on main grid 'columnist'